# How to merge multiple text files into one using cpanel cronjob

Tags: file, merge, cron, cpanel

Hello Stack Community,

quick question, I am trying to merge multiple text files into one using Cpanel cron job, here is a command I am using:

```
*   *   *   *   *   /home/xxx/public_html/yy/*.txt > /home/xxx/public_html/yy/joint.txt
```

The result file is empty

Answer (score 0):

The cronjob should look like this:

```
*   *   *   *   * for file in /home/xxx/public_html/yy/*.txt; do cat $file >> /home/xxx/public_html/yy/joint.txt; done
```

You basically search through all the files having **.txt** extension in **/home/xxx/public_html/yy/** and then you append the content of each of those files to the destination file (in your case, **joint.txt**).

Give it a try!